# Hiding Image in url and right click save option using Django

Tags: python, django

Iam using Django templates. I want to view image in webpages using django templates.But i want to restrict the image whenever we right click the image and click save as option and by taking html page source.
I have tried the link which is somehow similar which i want [Can I use Django to prevent direct access to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555023/can-i-use-django-to-prevent-direct-access-to-an-image-file)  In Session Middleware, if image path, i redirected it to same view from where it called,

```
for gated in settings.GATED_CONTENT:
            if path.startswith(gated) or path.endswith(gated):
                is_gated = True
                return redirect(reverse('my_view'))
```

By doing so, image is not displaying in webpage. Can Anyone help me?

Comment: You can't hide an image URL. All you can do is require people to login before seeing the image; is that what you want?

Comment: you can't prevent users from "save-as"ing your file, everything you send to a browser cannot be protected, if you block rightclick or so you can just go to the debug console and fetch it there. As Simeon says, you can however use django to only serve files to people who are authenticated, therefore requests should be routed to your django app and then a HTTPResponse with "image/png" should be returned (I guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you linked to doesn't do what you are asking (if I understand what you're asking correctly). You want to restrict people from being able to save an image that your site has served to their local machines (which can't be done).

The question you linked is about how to restrict image access to logged in users, probably to prevent hotlinking etc.

Comment: Yes, You are correct, I want to restrict people from being able to save an image from my page but they can view the image. Is there any possible thing with django?

Comment: It's not possible at all, not just in terms of django. Once you've served the image (as in, they can view it) they have access to the resource: it's already on their local machine and under their control.