# Prevent direct access to media files in Django

Tags: python, django

I added static path to my urls (Django 2.2 and python 3.6.9),

`static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

However, I would like to prevent unauthenticated access to media files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use Django to prevent direct access to an image file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555023/can-i-use-django-to-prevent-direct-access-to-an-image-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have django serve the media files, but this is not performant.

From [this blog post](https://blog.majsky.cz/django-protected-media-files/):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings


@login_required
def protected_serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    return serve(request, path, document_root, show_indexes)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], protected_serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

A better solution would be using [XSendfile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/) from NGINX.